# Set Time Default in UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I'm trying to populate a pickerView with a default value (String).  Currently I'm able to capture it's value as a time after the user interacts with it, however I'm not able to set the time value before it becomes visible to the user.

I've tried

```
let test = dateFormatter.date(from: "09:00 AM")
timePicker.setDate(test, animated: false)
```

however that errors "Value of type '(UIDatePicker) -> ()' has no member 'setDate'"

```
    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func timePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

      //my attempt at passing in a string
      let test = dateFormatter.date(from: "09:00 AM")
      timePicker.setDate(test, animated: false)

      tempTime = (dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))//successfully captures the user's input value
}
```

Here's the function that launches the xib (containing the timePicker)

```
    func showSomeDialogue() {
       let newVC = SomeViewContoller(nibName: "SomeViewController", bundle: nil)
       let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: newVC,
                               buttonAlignment: .horizontal,
                               transitionStyle: .bounceUp,
                               tapGestureDismissal: true,
                               panGestureDismissal: false)

       present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
        newVC.someDelegate = self as SomeDelegate
   }
```

The xib's class

```
import UIKit

protocol MealDelegate {
  func didCreateMeal(mealTime: String)
}

class SomeViewContoller: UIViewController {

 var someDelegate: SomeDelegate!
 var tempTime = ""

 @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!
 @IBAction func timePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    tempTime = (dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))
 }

 @IBAction func someSaveBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mealDelegate.didCreateMeal(mealTime: tempTime)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to set the default value in the function that is called when the picker value is changed. That function is for getting and handling the user-chosen value. Call setDate() upon viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you! I spent an hour working on this problem and somehow completely missed that.  The pickerView get's presented in a xib, so I'm guessing I should setDate() when that gets loaded?

Comment: @lajosdeme I just added an edit to show the xib function.

Comment: The class 'SomeViewController' must have a viewDidLoad and I guess that's the class where you wire up the date picker. Just set the default date there.

Comment: Hmmm...that's an extension of my ViewController.  Is there any way to set that in a variable?

Comment: Can you show me the code you have for 'SomeViewController'?

Comment: Updated to show the class

Comment: Step one, do not have a property and a method with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your SomeViewController class:

```
//MARK: - View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "10:57 PM")
    //or whatever date you want to display as default
    timePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Terrible way to create a date.

Comment: I just used the code the OP provided, since his question was not about the creation of the date.

Comment: I do agree that I'm not using an optimal way to use dates; passing around a string is the technique that works best in my scenario.

Comment: I still get "Value of type '(UIDatePicker) -> ()' has no member 'setDate'"

Comment: As @matt suggested, never have a method and a variable with the same name. This error is pretty clear, it's trying to get  setDate() of the method and not the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Add following to your view controller class:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "09:00 AM")
timePicker.date = date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 @IBAction func timePicker(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
                datePickerView.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

                sender.inputView = datePickerView
                datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTimePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    @objc func handleTimePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

           let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm "
               tempTime = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
       // view.endEditing(true)
       }
```